# Nano 33 IoT rescue from the dead: No USB. No upload mode

Tags: bootloader, reset

First of all: my board used to work fine.

Now my Nano 33 IoT turns ON (green light) when connected to USB on Mac but:

1. doesn't enter in upload mode after pressing twice on board button.
2. doesn't shows up in any serial port: nor `/dev/cu.usbmodem14*01`, neither `/dev/tty.usbmodem14*01`

For reasons too long to explain, I want to connect via ANY pins to the SAMD21 and force the burning of a new bootloader.

Is that possible in any way? Any idea is welcome!

Tx

Answer (score 2):

Use the SWD interface and a programmer to burn the bootloader to SAMD.

[image]

source of the picture https://medium.com/@manuel.bl/arduino-in-circuit-debugging-with-platformio-9f699da57ddc

I had luck with [Adafruit DAP library](https://learn.adafruit.com/programming-an-m0-using-an-arduino) using an Arduino M0 to burn a bootloader to MKR Zero.